# Expecting a type but actually getting a Maybe a0

Tags: json, haskell, types, aeson

I have a function which uses Aeson to get data from a json object within a file. The data and function are both defined below.

```
data Data = Data { date :: String
                   , temperature :: Int
                    } deriving (Show, Read, Generic)

data Temperatures = Temperatures { temperatures :: [Data]
                                 } deriving (Show, Generic)

mooStuff :: IO Temperatures
mooStuff  = decode <$> getFile
    where
        getFile = B.readFile "Hello.txt"
```

The file the function is using contains:

```
Data {date = "2015-02-28T20:16:12+00:00", temperature = 0}
Data {date = "2015-01-01T21:46:55+00:00", temperature = 2}
Data {date = "2015-04-08T21:46:53+00:00", temperature = 3}
Data {date = "2015-04-09T21:46:01+00:00", temperature = 4}
Data {date = "2015-04-10T21:46:40+00:00", temperature = 5}
Data {date = "2015-04-11T21:46:36+00:00", temperature = 6}
Data {date = "2015-04-12T20:36:25+00:00", temperature = 7}
```

However I'm getting a type error:

```
test.hs:37:13:
    Couldn't match type ‘Maybe a0’ with ‘Temperatures’
    Expected type: B.ByteString -> Temperatures
      Actual type: B.ByteString -> Maybe a0
    In the first argument of ‘(<$>)’, namely ‘decode’
    In the expression: decode <$> getFile
```

I've been staring at this for hours now, to no avail. Any ideas about where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for the error is that `decode` does not always succeed. Its type is

```
decode :: Data a => ByteString -> Maybe a
```

Correspondingly,

```
(decode <$>) :: Data a => IO ByteString -> IO (Maybe a)
                          -- desired type, IO Temperatures, won't unify
```

The type error message gives you the abstract `Maybe a0` as the actual type because it detects the conflict between `Maybe` and `Temperatures` before it gets anywhere near the point of choosing an appropriate instance for the `Data a` in the type of `decode`.

Your code needs to account for the possibility that the file delivers its contents but that they don't successfully `decode` to `Temperatures`.

Something like

```
do mt <- decode <$> getFile
   case mt of
     Nothing -> -- handle failure here
     Just t  -> return t
```

or if you're happy for `decode` failure to trigger an `IO` "user error", just

```
do Just t <- decode <$> getFile
   return t
```

Any way up, there's a failure mode that your code does not address, and that's what's surfacing as a type error.

Comment: Confirming my suspicion whilst providing a great response, thanks!